# ¿Cómo solucionar error de obtención de datos desde el COUNT MySQL?

Tags: mysql

He unido dos tablas sin problemas, pero en la última unión estoy presentando problemas, en específicamente en el `valuations` ya que me esta numerando valor a productos que no tienen valoración, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `prueba 1`, no tiene valoración (es decir ningún usuario voto por este producto) sin embargo me esta apareciendo el valor `(1)` en cambio el `prueba 2` si tiene dos usuarios que han votado por ese producto.

Entonces como puedo solucionar este pequeño error, esta es mi consulta:

```
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT co.id_course,
                                    au.author,
                                    ca.program_lang,
                                    co.study_program,
                                    co.launch,
                                    co.start_date,
                                    co.release_date,
                                    co.title_course,
                                    co.subtitle_course,
                                    co.price_old,
                                    co.price,
                                    co.url,
                                    AVG(ra.rating) AS avg_rating,
                                    COUNT(*) valuations
                            FROM tbl_courses co
                            JOIN tbl_category ca ON co.category = ca.id_category
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_author au ON co.author = au.id_user
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_ratings ra ON co.id_course = ra.id_course
                            WHERE ca.program_lang = ? AND co.active = ?
                            GROUP BY co.id_course
                            ORDER BY co.id_course DESC
                            LIMIT ?");
```

Comment: Sin ver un set de datos real poco podemos decirte. Intenta cambiar los `LEFT JOIN` por `INNER JOIN` y prueba así. Si no funciona, ve quitando JOIN uno a uno hasta que el error desparezca, entonce sabrá que el error será en esa tabla que quitaste del JOIN. Para este tipo de problemas es preciso ver los datos concretamente. Si quieres que te ayudemos desde aquí puedes [crear un fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) con tablas y datos de ejemplo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si le agrego un `INNER JOIN` sino existen datos no me va imprimir los productos, eso no me conviene por eso no agrego  `INNER JOIN` porque si no existen datos en `tbl_ratings` me deben aparecer las estrellas sin pintar y, con datos de 0.0 promedio y, 0 personas votadas.

Comment: Lo sugerí como forma inmediata de depuración simplemente. Como ya dije, sin ver datos concretos en poco podemos ayudarte aquí. Los datos se duplican por algún motivo que no podemos adivinar viendo la consulta sin más. No sabemos qué datos hay en cada tabla, ni cómo se relacionan. Crea un fiddle basado en datos para que podamos ver cuál es el problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano Esto me comentaron *aunque es el efecto de un grupo por. la combinación sin funciones de grupo por o agregadas en la selección produciría una fila para cada calificación para cada curso. agregar el grupo por lo convierte en una fila para cada curso, y hace que el promedio y el recuento sean para todas las filas agrupadas que se habrían producido sin el grupo por, que son todas las calificaciones (aunque el recuento (*) producirá 1 incluso si no hay calificaciones; si desea 0 para un curso sin calificaciones, necesita contar (ra.valuations) o algún otro campo no nulo en ra.)*

Comment: Aquí interviene 4 tablas, cada una con datos y relacionadas entre sí. Sin ver lo que hay en cada tabla y cómo son las relaciones es difícil decirte *el error está aquí o allí*. En este tipo de casos uno va añadiendo los JOIN uno a uno y así cuando hay un problema se sabe que está en la última tabla que incorporaste al JOIN, por eso te sugerí que hicieras lo inverso: ir quitando los JOIN uno a uno, y cuando veas los datos correctos sabrás que el error está en la última tabla que quitaste. Si nunca ves los datos correctos entonces el error estará en los datos en sí mismos y deberás revisarlos.

Comment: @A.Cedano Los otros datos funcionaba bien amigo, lo que pasa es que quise hacer una consulta dentro de un ciclo (`While`) de la siguiente manera: https://ideone.com/URSo1H entonces intente en agregar esos datos de esa consulta que esta dentro del ciclo (`While`) a la consulta principal.

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres con *los otros datos*. ¿Esta consulta ejecutada directamente en el SGBD funciona bien? Si es eso, entonces el problema no es la consulta, sino el código que usas para leer los datos. Y, si es la consulta la que arroja datos erróneos debes verificar las tablas, las relaciones entre ellas y los datos en cada tabla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes estos dos valores:

```
AVG(ra.rating) AS avg_rating,
COUNT(*) valuations
```

El primero saca la media de los ratings, el segundo cuenta el número de filas... tengan rating o no.
Prueba a usar

```
COUNT(ra.rating)
```

Porque count no sumará una fila si el campo rating es `null`.

Comment: Gracias funciono correctamente :)